# Protobuf isn't converting .proto files into .py ones

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm stuck at the Installation guide of tensorflow object detection API, that's the line from it that doesn't work when I try it:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Even if I try and manually install fresh version of protobuf, it doesn't help.

**System information:**

1. Ubuntu 18.0.4
2. protobuf 3.0.0
3. tensorflow 2.0

I do all the stuff with durectories but when I run that line above, none of .proto files are converting to .py

Comment: In the [dependencies](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#dependencies) section **TensorFlow 1.15.0** is listed. Please verify that you have got the right dependencies installed. When you [compile](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation) the proto files, do you get any errors? Please add the errors in the question.

Comment: And, did you try the alternative [manual installation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#manual-protobuf-compiler-installation-and-usage)?

Comment: Yes, I tried and installed protobuf manually and refered to downloaded version of protoc, but it didn't help.

I'll try to check all the dependencies or even uninstall everything and start again, thanks for the tip! I was thinking of tf2 as wrong too, but it was used in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb this tutorial so I've thought it's ok.

Comment: But I still don't understand why there isn't any errors, just silence. Why protobuf isn't reporting any errors?

Comment: I guess you should try with the TF1.15.0. Question: `protoc` just gets stuck with no output? What is its behavior on the terminal?

Comment: FYI: Downloaded the models repo and built all the protos successfully. One warning: `object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto: warning: Import object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto but not used.` Commented the import.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try later and comment on how it goes, for now I deleted Ubuntu and will reinstall it.